# Why can't I declare and define a char-pointer variable to point to a char-array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, initialization

What's wrong with the initialization of `s2` in the code below?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char *s1 = "foo";
  char *s2 = {'f', 'o', 'o', '\0'};

  printf("%c\n", s1[1]);
  printf("%c\n", s2[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

I thought because I could initialize `s1` the way I did above, the initialization of `s2` should work fine as well.

But this code leads to compile-time warnings as well as run-time segmentation fault.

```
$ gcc foo.c
foo.c: In function ‘main’:
foo.c:6: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
foo.c:6: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
foo.c:6: warning: (near initialization for ‘s2’)
foo.c:6: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
foo.c:6: warning: (near initialization for ‘s2’)
foo.c:6: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
foo.c:6: warning: (near initialization for ‘s2’)
$ ./a.out
o
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, because `{'f', 'o', 'o', '\0'};` is a brace-enclosed intializer list. It cannot be used to initialize a *pointer variable*, in any way. However, it can be used to initialize a `char` array, like

```
 char s2[] = {'f', 'o', 'o', '\0'};
```

because ***arrays are not pointers***.

For your case, you can try using a [compound literal](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3/gcc/Compound-Literals.html) instead as a workaround.

Something like

```
  char *s2 = (char []){'f', 'o', 'o', '\0'};
```

---

Just to add some additional info, which can arise after reading this answer, like then why / how it is possible to initialize an array with string literal, like

```
  char s3[] = "Hello";
```

is possible, because as mentioned in `C11`, chapter §6.7.9, *initialization*

> An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal or UTF−8 string
>   literal, optionally enclosed in braces. Successive bytes of the string literal (including the
>   terminating null character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the
>   elements of the array.

Comment: Are we are creating an intializer list and then typecast, so it will create this unnamed(internally named) [ ] temporarily ? and assign its address to s2? I mean regarding your answer `char *s2 = (char []){'f', 'o', 'o', '\0'};`

Comment: @SuvP: Compound literals are lvalues with automatic storage duration that extends until the end of the containing scope.

Comment: @SuvP `s2` is an array and cannot be _assigned_ . We're just creating an  unnamed object with automatic storage __here__ to initialize the elements of `s2`. FWIW, in global scope, a compound literal will have static storage duration.

Answer (score 4):

A better question to ask is why you can initialize a pointer with a string literal, because inability to initialize a pointer using an array initializer should come as no surprise: after all, arrays are not pointers.

String literals, however, are special. C lets you use them to initialize both arrays and pointers in order to provide a convenient syntax for creating null-terminated strings. That is why your first syntax works with both an array of characters and a character pointer.

Answer (score 1):

[Designated initializers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html) `{}` initialize the data on the left of `=`. For example

```
int a[6] = { 0, 0, 15, 0, 29, 0 };
```

initializes array of 6 integers, that is why each of elements in initializer list is integer.

In your example of

```
char *s2 = {'f', 'o', 'o', '\0'};
```

you would therefore attempt to initialize pointer to char with integer values of characters which is not what you wanted. To initialize character array you can use

```
char s2[] = {'f', 'o', 'o', '\0'};
```

syntax, or

```
char s2[] = "foo"; /* also allowed in C, as dasblinkenlight noted - the better
                    * question would be why this works and Sourav Ghosh gave
                    * the answer */
```